# Chrome issue with responsivenest

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, responsiveness

I have my website: http://david.addagio.cz

And I have it fully responsive.

But I have one problem and I don't really know why. If I have my website in **'phone mode'**, it's all right in **Google Chrome browser**, but in many other browsers it makes something like 'padding' on the left side. I don't know why. All css are just great, but it keeps that weard padding, even if I have `padding:0;` Check out my website and **please** help me.

Comment: Try seeing if it has to do with margin or borders. Some browsers calculate widths of elements differently.

Comment: When I emulate in IE, I get thrown an error `Object doesn't support property or method 'on'` at `main.js, Line: 70, Column: 3` and then the page has strange margins as described. Adding `padding: 0;` to `#main-header ul` fixes the problem in Firefox emulation.